# What exactly causes the normal force and how is it related to friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, friction, contact-mechanics

So I've read many answers on the internet and have not yet come to understand the origin of the normal force.

What I've to come to understand about the normal force, is that it is the electromagnetic repulsion between the electrons of the two surfaces which come into contact with one another(is this right?)

Secondly, I've read about asperities and the formation of cold welds between the asperities
I understand the cold welds are due to bonds formed between the atoms in contact at the surface.

[image]

So here there are two forces, one is the repulsion and the other is the attraction forming bonds between surfaces. Which one of them is the normal force?

How exactly do any of these forces cause friction?

[image]

f1 is the force trying to move the body, but f2 is the force trying to restore the body

In the picture above, suppose I am trying to move one surface over another. Bonds have already been formed between the two surfaces, so when I try to move the objects relative to one another, the bonds oppose the motion, and try to restore it back to the original position. Do I think of friction this way?

Please bear in mind I'm a student still in high school so kindly explain it as if you were explaining it at a fairly non advanced level.

Comment: Ignoring molecular interactions, if two surfaces are exerting a force on each other, the component of that force which is perpendicular to the surface is defined as the normal force, and the parallel component is defined as the friction force (for each surface).